# Renovating Restroom

Tags: plumbing, renovation

I live in Arizona and I’m renovating my restroom. I live in a duplex home. My vanity is located on the wall that is shared with my neighbor. Is there any building code regarding plumbing behind that wall we share? I’m thinking of rerouting the plumbing of the vanity.

Comment: Are you moving the plumbing _into_ the shared wall, or is it already in that wall and you just want to move it to a new location? Also, where in AZ, as city code might override state code.

Comment: Yes Im trying to move it into the share wall. I live in Chandler.

Comment: Please [edit] that info into your question. Not everyone will catch it down here in the comments.